# SQliteDatabase data is duplicated

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i am beginning  in SQLiteDatabase  i am trying to insert data where i fetch it from  Internet   and i am using asynTask  to fetch data and insert it
but data is duplicate in recycleview  when  rotate the mobile and  when  reload  activity  or login to activity

below is my code

```
     @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

        JSONObject json = jsonFromHttp.makeHttpRequest(URLS.CATEGORIES_URL, "Get", params);
        try {
           JSONArray products = json.getJSONArray("cat1");
            for (int i=0;i<  products.length();i++) {




                JSONObject Arrobj= products.getJSONObject(i);

                String cat_id=Arrobj.getString("cat_id");
                String cat_name=Arrobj.getString("cat_name");
                String cat_photo=Arrobj.getString("cat_photo");
                Integer id=Integer.parseInt(cat_id);
```

//  here i insert data

```
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME, cat_name);
                values.put(DataContract.DataEntry.CATEGORY_ID, id);
                values.put(DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_IMAGE, "mm");}

                Uri newUri = getContext().getContentResolver().insert(DataContract.DataEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);

                categoriesList.add(new CategoryModel(cat_name,cat_photo,cat_id,"","")); //put object which carry values in list
```

i don't know  how to solve this problem .

Comment: I am guessing that your `cat_id` is not primary key.

Comment: do you what happens when you rotate your device?

Comment: @Enzokie     yes it not primary key  i need this

Comment: @matrix    when rotate  data is duplicated

Comment: @matrix  and when reload activity  data is duplicated

Comment: first remove old data from SQLite and insert new in database.

Comment: @Enzokie  thanks  the solution  is to make  cat_id  is  primary key

Answer (score 0):

i make cat_id is primary key  this prevent data to duplicate

Comment: @Enzokie  it is as you said